# Dynamic Change Column Values with NEW in Trigger Function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Is it possible to dynamically change column values in NEW with a Trigger Function?

Triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER lowercase_username_on_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE lowercase_on_insert('username');

CREATE TRIGGER lowercase_email_on_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE lowercase_on_insert('email');
```

Trigger Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lowercase_on_insert()
RETURNS trigger
AS $lowercase_on_insert$
    BEGIN
        -- e.g., NEW.username = LOWER(NEW.username)
        --  -OR- NEW.email = LOWER(NEW.email)
        EXECUTE FORMAT('NEW.%s = LOWER(NEW.%s);', TG_ARGV[0], TG_ARGV[0]);
        RETURN NEW;
    END
$lowercase_on_insert$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get an `ERROR: syntax error at or new "NEW"` whenever I run an INSERT.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Comment: Please refer to these answers, pointing out the usage of `hstore` as a means to dynamically choose the column of NEW to access/modify: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82039/assign-to-new-by-key-in-a-postgres-trigger and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127787/trigger-function-taking-column-names-as-parameters-to-modify-the-row

Answer (score 0):

Change your Trigger function as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lowercase() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN        
        NEW.username = LOWER(NEW.username);
        NEW.email = LOWER(NEW.email);
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and assign

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgrr BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE lowercase();
```

***OR***

You can directly apply `lower()` function in Insert/Update like this

```
insert into users(username,email) values (lower('Jerry'),lower('JeRRY@mail.COM')); 

update users set username=lower('JERRY'),email=lower('JERRY@MAIL.COM') where id =1
```

Comment: can the trigger be made dynamically? trying to make one and use it for different trigger cases